# __NSCFString size Error when calling image out of dictionary and into imageview

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, xcode5

I've got multiple pieces of JSON'd data being pulled into an array called "jsonArray". I'm calling each of the text items out of the array and displaying them in UILabels successfully. But, the image that is in jsonArray is not playing well with the imageview on my view controller. I can see that the data for the image is being stored successfully:

[image]

The error that I'm receiving is "**reason: '-[__NSCFString size]**" I'm not sure where to go from here. My code is below. (I've got dynamic prototype cells, so I have created a separate class for the cell itself.)

**FeedTableViewController.m**

```
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    [tableView reloadData]; // if tableView is unidentified make the tableView IBOutlet
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return jsonArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NeedCardTableViewCell *cell = (NeedCardTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"needCard" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *needs = jsonArray[indexPath.row]; // get the data dict for the row
    cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
    cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
    cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];
    cell.imageProfPic.image = [needs objectForKey:@"userImage"];

    return cell;
}
```

**NeedCardTableViewCell.h**

```
@interface NeedCardTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedPoster;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedDescrip;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageProfPic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Comment: [needs objectForKey:@"userImage"] is not an image, it's a URL, so you can't set the image property of your image view to it.

Comment: @rdelmar yeah, I'm figuring that out. How would you go about retrieving the image from the url and displaying it in the imageview? Is that something that has to be done asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what exactly is `[needs objectForKey:@"userImage"];` returning? Is its a string of a URL, or a block of data?

If its a block of data then you might say something like: `cell.imageProfPic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[needs objectForKey:@"userImage"]];`

If its a URL string then you should asynchronously load it and then update using the data when its ready.

EDIT: Now that I know its a string, the following will work

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[needs objectForKey:@"userImage"]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.imageView.image = image;
    });

});
```

Comment: Inside the key "userImage" is the image's URL. I tried to use your snippet of code just incase, but it returned an error [__NSCFString bytes]. Could you elaborate on loading it asynchronously? I've found an SO question on it, but I didn't fully understand because my issue involves objectForKey

Comment: The key "userImage" returns a string containing the image's URL. It's an NSString. You are trying to assign an NSString to the NSImage in an image view. That's not going to work. You'll have to actually download the image.

Comment: @gnasher729 mind throwing your thoughts into answer form? I've come to the same conclusion you've given...but no one is stepping up to help me figure out how to actually do it.